# How to fill missing data (not NA value) with value 0?

Tags: r

My data are like:

```
 Date Value
00:00    10
01:00     8
02:00     1
04:00     4
...
```

Some data are missing if the `value=0`. My question is how to fill these data back in. Like, after `02:00 17`, fill in a row `03:00 0`.

I have done some search, but only found solutions to replace `NAs` with `0`. In my case, my data are not even showing in the data frame. Is there a way to check whether there's a gap between adjacent data?

Comment: what about `dd <- data.frame(hour = c(1, 2, 4), value = c(10, 4, 8)); dm <- data.frame(hour = 1:10); out <- merge(dm, dd, all = TRUE); out[is.na(out)] <- 0` where dd is the data you have, dm represents the full sequence you want, merge them, and replace the NA with 0

Comment: Could you show some more examples about what you wanted to do? I didn't quite understand what you were saying there "Like, after 02:00 17, fill in a row 03:00 0" -- did you mean the row with 02:00 1?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

data = data.frame(Date=as.Date(c('2015-03-20','2015-03-24','2015-03-25','2015-03-28')), 
                  Value=c(1,2,3,4)) 

#        Date Value
#1 2015-03-20     1
#2 2015-03-24     2
#3 2015-03-25     3
#4 2015-03-28     4

dt = data.table(Date=seq(min(data$Date), max(data$Date), by='days'))
setkey(setDT(data), Date)[dt][!data, Value:=0][]

#         Date Value
#1: 2015-03-20     1
#2: 2015-03-21     0
#3: 2015-03-22     0
#4: 2015-03-23     0
#5: 2015-03-24     2
#6: 2015-03-25     3
#7: 2015-03-26     0
#8: 2015-03-27     0
#9: 2015-03-28     4
```

It is basically a join on the resampling table - `setkey(setDT(data), Date)[dt]` - you want (you have to define it, here this is `dt`). Then you replace values not present in your original dataset with `0`'s - `[!data, Value:=0]`

Comment: Another way, just for fun: `data[, data.table(Date=seq(min(Date), max(Date), by='1 day'), Value=0, key="Date")][data, Value := i.Value][]`

Comment: Maybe I should upgrade my version of `data.table` because key is not a valid argument for `setDT` on my side? Really good one liner, I can't compete with a data.table developer ;)

Comment: Thanks :-). On `setDT()`, it doesn't have a `key` argument yet... I was thinking out loud :-). Could be nicer to do `setDT(..., key = )` instead of `setkey(setDT(...), ...)`.

Comment: Thanks Colonel and Arun. I got an error and had some trouble understanding. `setkey(setDT(data), Date)` is setting the "Date" column to be the key of "data", right？ And `[dt]` is doing a join, so after the join, the Values missing would be "NA"s?  `[!data, Value:=0]` is then replacing NA's with 0? What does the last two brackets mean? @Colonel Beauvel    @Arun

Comment: Hi Sophie, all your interpretation is correct! The last brackets are just a way to display the so-created `data.table` in the consola (you can type the command by omitting them and see the difference). You can also do `result=setkey(setDT(data), Date)[dt][!data, Value:=0]` and then type `result`

Answer (score 2):

Two simple ways I can think of in base r:

```
s <- format(seq(s <- as.POSIXct('2000-01-01'), s + 3.6e4, by = 'hour'), '%H:%M')
# [1] "00:00" "01:00" "02:00" "03:00" "04:00" "05:00" "06:00" "07:00" "08:00"
# [10] "09:00" "10:00"
ss <- s[c(1:3, 5)]
dd <- data.frame(hour = ss, value = c(10, 8, 1, 4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#    hour value
# 1 00:00    10
# 2 01:00     8
# 3 02:00     1
# 4 04:00     4
```

I made two sample vectors, `s` are the times you want to fill in, and `ss` are the times in your data frame that you have. presumably you already have both of these, so then you can

1. create a data frame with the sequence of times you want and merge the two with `all = TRUE` so that there are no duplicates; then replace the `NA` with 0

---

```
dm <- data.frame(hour = s)
out <- merge(dm, dd, all = TRUE)

#     hour value
# 1  00:00    10
# 2  01:00     8
# 3  02:00     1
# 4  03:00    NA
# 5  04:00     4
# 6  05:00    NA
# 7  06:00    NA
# 8  07:00    NA
# 9  08:00    NA
# 10 09:00    NA
# 11 10:00    NA

out[is.na(out)] <- 0

#     hour value
# 1  00:00    10
# 2  01:00     8
# 3  02:00     1
# 4  03:00     0
# 5  04:00     4
# 6  05:00     0
# 7  06:00     0
# 8  07:00     0
# 9  08:00     0
# 10 09:00     0
# 11 10:00     0
```

2. or you can give the exact hours you want in a vector or take the set difference between the times you want and the times you have and order the results:

---

```
## giving the times explicitly
out <- rbind(dd, data.frame(hour = sprintf('%02s:00', c(3, 5:10)), value = 0))
## or more programmatically:
out <- rbind(dd, data.frame(hour = setdiff(s, dd$hour),
                            value = 0))
out[order(out$hour), ]

#     hour value
# 1  00:00    10
# 2  01:00     8
# 3  02:00     1
# 5  03:00     0
# 4  04:00     4
# 6  05:00     0
# 7  06:00     0
# 8  07:00     0
# 9  08:00     0
# 10 09:00     0
# 11 10:00     0
```